# Морфологический разбор слова

Tags: словообразование, морфология

Самое главное.

I. Местоимение, указывает на признак, отвечает на вопрос **какое**?
II. Начальная форма - самый. Морфологические признаки:

А) постоянные:

1. местоимение-прилагательное;
2. определительное.

Б) Непостоянные:

1. именительный падеж;
2. единственное число;
3. средний род.

III. В предложении является определением.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, верно ли я выполнил разбор? Может быть, есть что-то лишнее здесь или чего-то не хватает?

Comment: И ещё вопрос: слово "главное" здесь является существительным?

Answer (score 1):

по - моему, это можно расценивать и как сложную превосходную степень прилагательного. Нужен контекст.